# Code::Blocks, как заставить IDE сохранять файлы в UTF-8

Tags: c, utf-8, codeblocks, ansi

Проблема следующая: если мне необходимо добавить в проект новый *.c или *.h файл, то я нажимаю **New file** и создаю его, автоматически добавляя.

Но файл создается в **ANSI**. Как настроить автоматическое сохранение в **utf-8**? Ручное конвертирование через блокнот уже порядком утомило.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Menu `Settings`->`Editor...`->`General Settings`.
Далее выбираете закладку `"Encoding settings"`.

Выбираете из выпадающего списка любимую кодировку (UTF-8).
И чуть ниже ставите ее как `"As default"`.

Как-то так.

Comment: Так работает, но только в том случае, если в файле имеются кириллические символы. Если просто сделать файл **test.c**, внести в него лишь одну строку **#include <stdlib.h>**, то файл все равно остается в **ANSI**.

Comment: Ну, тогда Вам стоит что-то почитать про кодировку UTF-8 :-). Для ASCII символов - UTF-8 совпадает с однобайтовыми кодировками на основе ASCII и ANSI. И Вы сможете заметить ее присутствие только введя символы из других языков. Это если очень грубо и кратко.

Comment: Точно, значит это баг просмотрщика, который **utf-8** с одной лишь латиницей видит, как **ANSI**.

Comment: Это не баг. Это преднамеренно так сделано - он же пытается из текста определить кодировку. А раз там только однобайтовые символы - он и использует как первое приближение ANSI.

Comment: Я разобрался, спасибо.