# Telegtam API Отправить текст Кириллицу через с++ curl

Tags: c++, telegram-bot, curl, telegram, g++

Создал простенькую функцию отправки сообщения в телеграм группу, но английский тест отправляет, а русский нет, при этом в тестовый скрипт отправляет и возвращает отлично, подскажите в чём ошибка. Это все на виндовс, тестовый скрип в том числе. Прошу обратить внимание что тестовый скрипт HTTP А телеграм HTTPS. Чистый g++ CodeClocks

Токит и ид конечно же скрыты

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <curl\curl.h>
    #include <string>
    #include<fstream>
    #include <chrono>
    #include<ctime>
    #include<vector>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <windows.h>
    
    
    //Функцыя обработки возвратных данных скорее всего
    size_t curlWriteFunc(char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string *buffer)
    {
            size_t result = 0;
            if (buffer != NULL)
            {
                    buffer->append(data, size * nmemb);
                    result = size * nmemb;
            }
            return result;
    }
    
    std::string SendPost(std::string url,std::string post,std::string &source)
    {
          // буфер для сохранения текстовых ошибок
            char curlErrorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
            std::string curlBuffer;
    
            CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
            if (curl) {
                    //Ошыбки писать в curlErrorBuffer
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, curlErrorBuffer);
                    // задаем URL...
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
                    // переходить по "Location:" указаному в HTTP заголовке учет пнренаправлений
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                    // не проверять сертификат удаленного сервера они оыбочни часто почему то
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); //O
                    // использовать метод POST для отправки данных
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    // параметры POST
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post.c_str());
                    // функция, вызываемая cURL для записи полученых данных.
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &curlBuffer);
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curlWriteFunc);
                    //Кодировка
                    //  curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Accept-Charset: WINDOWS-1251");
    
                    // выполнить запрос
                    CURLcode curlResult = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                    // завершение сеанса
                    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    
                    //Удача всё ок
                    if (curlResult == CURLE_OK)
                    {
                        //std::cout<<curlBuffer;
                           // ret+=curlBuffer;
                           source = curlBuffer;
                           return "";
                    } else { //Ошыбочка
                            //std::cout << "error(" << curlResult << "): " << curlErrorBuffer << std::endl;
                            std::stringstream convert;
                            convert << "error(" << curlResult << "): " << curlErrorBuffer << std::endl;
                            return convert.str();
                    }
            }
            else
                //std::cout<<"curl nooo init\n";
        return "curl nooo init\n";
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        SetConsoleCP(1251);
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    
    
    std::string source = "";
    std::string post = "z=текст для отправки&all=еще что то";
    std::string url = "http://test.zp";
    
    if(SendPost(url,post,source) == "")
    {
        std::cout<<source<<std::endl;
    }
    
    std::string toket = "2*********8:A****6-2**********************M"; //Токит который выдають после создания бота так сказать пароль
    std::string chatID = "-6********3"; //ИД групы телеграм в которой бот куда и писать будет
    
    url =  std::string("https://api.telegram.org/bot") + toket + std::string("/sendMessage"); // -d
    post = "chat_id=" + chatID + "&text=";
    post+="Привет телеграм";
    if(SendPost(url,post,source) == "")
    {
        std::cout<<"zp1:"<<source<<std::endl;
    }
    
    
    url =  std::string("https://api.telegram.org/bot") + toket + std::string("/sendMessage"); // -d
    post = "chat_id=" + chatID + "&text=";
    post+="Hello telegram";
    if(SendPost(url,post,source) == "")
    {
        std::cout<<"zp2:"<<source<<std::endl;
    }
    }
```

php Тестовый локальный

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['z']))
{
    echo "Post: " . $_POST['z'];
    file_put_contents("POST.txt","Get: " . $_GET['z']);
}
if(isset($_GET['z']))
{
    echo "Get: " . $_GET['z'];
    file_put_contents("GET.txt","Get: " . $_GET['z']);
}
?>
```

Что вижу в консоли

```
Post: текст для отправки
zp1:{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: strings must be encoded in UTF-8"}
zp2:{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":69,"from":{"id":2**********,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"M********t_bot","username":"Yong************Bot"},"chat":{"id":-6*******,"title":"\ud83e\ude93******** club\u26cf\ufe0f","type":"group","all_members_are_administrators":true},"date":1636892306,"text":"Hello telegram"}}
```

Comment: Вам же явно пишет - строка должна быть закодирована в UTF-8. В чем она у Вас - не понятно, но скорее всего cp1251.

Comment: Вроде пробовал перекодировать но не помогло, скорее всего корявый код нашел, вот тут адекватный https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783946/Конвертировать-в-кодировку-utf8 нашел функцию которая исправила все, отправило русский текст, но может подскажете возможно есть стандартные функции для кодировки, иле готовые библиотеки для различных перекодировок? Но в любом случаи благодарю, код заработал

Comment: в стандартном с++ есть (или наверно лучше говорить были) функции c codecvt, но их посчитали очень сложными в использовании. Как по мне, то лучший способ не иметь проблем с utf-8 - использовать сразу его (можно исходники сохранить в нем). правда тогда возникают вопросы с выводом на экран и другие.

Comment: Благодарю нашёл ка настроить здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/874904/codeblocks-как-заставить-ide-сохранять-файлы-в-utf-8 Ето уже второй вариант ответа который сработал

Answer (score 0):

Как отметил **KoVadim** Нужно конвертировать строку в utf-8 что видно из ответа от телеграм. Обычно в Виндовс проектах кодировка cp1251.

**Есть 2 пути**

**Путь 1** конвертировать cp1251 в utf-8 каждый раз перед отправкой. Теоретически можно с файла считывать текст сразу в нужной кодировке.

**Путь 2** пере сохранить исходный файл каким либо редактором в кодировку utf-8 и настроить ide чтобы и дальше сохраняла в utf-8 но
тогда в при выводе в консоль нужно будит конвертировать с utf-8 cp1251

**Как настроить CodeBlocks**

 Menu **Settings->Editor...->General Settings.** Далее выбираете закладку "**Encoding settings**".

Выбираете из выпадающего списка любимую кодировку **(UTF-8)**. И чуть ниже ставите ее как "**As default**"

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/874904/codeblocks-как-заставить-ide-сохранять-файлы-в-utf-8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/874904/codeblocks-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-ide-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-utf-8)

---

**Конвертировать  cp1251 в utf-8 и обратно  utf-8 cp1251** 

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783946/Конвертировать-в-кодировку-utf8

Код дублирую так как сам не переношу когда отправляют на силку

cp1251_to_utf8

```
string cp1251_to_utf8(const char *str){
    string res; 
    int result_u, result_c;
    result_u = MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, str, -1, 0, 0);
    if(!result_u ){return 0;}
    wchar_t *ures = new wchar_t[result_u];
    if(!MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, str, -1, ures, result_u)){
        delete[] ures;
        return 0;
    }
    result_c = WideCharToMultiByte(65001, 0, ures, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    if(!result_c){
        delete [] ures;
        return 0;
    }
    char *cres = new char[result_c];
    if(!WideCharToMultiByte(65001, 0, ures, -1, cres, result_c, 0, 0)){
        delete[] cres;
        return 0;
    }
    delete[] ures;
    res.append(cres);
    delete[] cres;
    return res;
}
```

Utf8_to_cp1251

```
std::string Utf8_to_cp1251(const char *str)
{
    std::string res;
    int result_u, result_c;

    result_u = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,
        0,
        str,
        -1,
        0,
        0);

    if (!result_u)
        return 0;

    wchar_t *ures = new wchar_t[result_u];

    if(!MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,
        0,
        str,
        -1,
        ures,
        result_u))
    {
        delete[] ures;
        return 0;
    }

    result_c = WideCharToMultiByte(
        1251,
        0,
        ures,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        0, 0);

    if(!result_c)
    {
        delete [] ures;
        return 0;
    }

    char *cres = new char[result_c];

    if(!WideCharToMultiByte(
        1251,
        0,
        ures,
        -1,
        cres,
        result_c,
        0, 0))
    {
        delete[] cres;
        return 0;
    }
    delete[] ures;
    res.append(cres);
    delete[] cres;
    return res;
}
```

Проверка на UTF8:

```
bool is_valid_utf8(const char * string){
    if(!string){return true;}
    const unsigned char * bytes = (const unsigned char *)string;
    unsigned int cp;
    int num;
    while(*bytes != 0x00){
        if((*bytes & 0x80) == 0x00){
            // U+0000 to U+007F 
            cp = (*bytes & 0x7F);
            num = 1;
        }
        else if((*bytes & 0xE0) == 0xC0){
            // U+0080 to U+07FF 
            cp = (*bytes & 0x1F);
            num = 2;
        }
        else if((*bytes & 0xF0) == 0xE0){
            // U+0800 to U+FFFF 
            cp = (*bytes & 0x0F);
            num = 3;
        }
        else if((*bytes & 0xF8) == 0xF0){
            // U+10000 to U+10FFFF 
            cp = (*bytes & 0x07);
            num = 4;
        }
        else{return false;}
        bytes += 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < num; ++i){
            if((*bytes & 0xC0) != 0x80){return false;}
            cp = (cp << 6) | (*bytes & 0x3F);
            bytes += 1;
        }
        if( (cp > 0x10FFFF) ||
            ((cp <= 0x007F) && (num != 1)) || 
            ((cp >= 0xD800) && (cp <= 0xDFFF)) ||
            ((cp >= 0x0080) && (cp <= 0x07FF)  && (num != 2)) ||
            ((cp >= 0x0800) && (cp <= 0xFFFF)  && (num != 3)) ||
            ((cp >= 0x10000)&& (cp <= 0x1FFFFF)&& (num != 4)) ){return false;}
    }
    return true;
}
```

string в wstring:

```
wstring string_to_wstring(string str){
    wstring convertedString;
    int requiredSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), -1, 0, 0);
    if( requiredSize > 0){
        vector<wchar_t> buffer(requiredSize);
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), -1, &buffer[0], requiredSize);
        convertedString.assign(buffer.begin(), buffer.end() - 1);
    }
    return convertedString;
}
```